# Method in button onclick is running even if button is not clicked

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete or set node values to null in my firebase database, but the the method inside my onClick listener is running without me pressing the button.

```
 btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Orders").child(user_id);

                     myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                        {

                            myRef.child("Session").setValue(null);
                          //  myRef.child("Dabba Type").removeValue();
                          //  myRef.child("Start date").removeValue();
                          //  myRef.child("End date").removeValue();
                           // myRef.child("Address").removeValue();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                        {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: set a breakpoint and check if specific this line ever executes, maybe you have code somewhere else that causing problem..

Comment: Whenever you click a button for the first time, the code sets a `ValueEventListener` (so `onDataChange` is called automatically whenever value changes)

Comment: so what can I do so that it does not run automatically

Comment: If you don't want the listener to run, don't attach it. But it's really unclear what you're trying to accomplish. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change/modify data, then `setValue()` alone is enough. You don't need to attach `addValueEventListener`. Like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    database.getReference("Orders").child(user_id).child).child("Session").setValue(null);
}
```

---

> Additional info (maybe will not work if applied to the code in question, but this information likely to be useful)

If you also want to read the value first before committing any change (like confirming if is true then change it to false and otherwise), then you should consider using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener`. Because it only do your code once while the later is keep listening to any data change that happen until you remove/detach the listener. And in this case, you should do it like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Orders").child(user_id);
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class)) {
                // if value is true, change data
                myRef.setValue(false);
    ...
```

Hope this helps